# Space between first and second line between grid gallery

Tags: css, css-grid

```
.gallery{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
grid-template-rows: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
```

}
[grid image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWsZw.png)

can you tell me what the heck is spacing between first and second line? other line works perfect. I have also declared `*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;}` 
please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: `grid-template-rows: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );` gives an height of 250px to the first row, then, since there is no height on .gallery nothing more happens beside stretching up .gallery. what you want is `grid-auto-rows: minmax(250px,1fr);`

Comment: replace `grid-template-rows: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );` by grid-auto-rows:250px

Comment: thank you a lot, `grid-auto-rows` worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css is creating grid items of 250 long each,and the constant is not that much in height in that div, so its taking the full height I.E 250px,
Check this
https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example28/

So just make rows auto as per the content in it

```css
.gallery{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
grid-template-rows: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; height: 100px;"></div>
</div>
```